# how to remove the duplicate canonical tag

Tags: magento-1.9, seo

We have a canonical tag on the product page of the website. But there are 2 tags.how can remove one canonical tag on the product page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing same issue. I was remove one canonical tag in code file and my issue was fixed.

Magento allow to add  canonical tag via using set in admin.

> Use Canonical Link Tag for Products: Yes

I guess in your website backend already set Use Canonical Link Tag for Products: Yes

And manually one Canonical Link added in code file.

As per my suggestion find canonical tag in code file and remove that. And check one canonical tag is comes.

Hope it helpful!

Comment: "As per my suggestion find the canonical tag in the code file and remove that. And check one canonical tag it comes."


can you please tell me which code file?

Comment: You can find in your app/ directory. I guess it will in 
 any modules or themes files.